# how does spark provide a web service in real time?

Tags: scala, web, apache-spark

I am working with Spark.

I want the Spark application to be a long running application which doesn't exit after it finishes computation and to listen for HTTP requests and return the computed data.

How can I do it out-of-the box? Now, I can only write a while loop to ensure the program keeps going.

Comment: check https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: @shekhar that's not exactly what he wants, I think he is looking for something like a long running job that would also act as a server (something like Spark Streaming app which would also have an HTTP endpoint).

Comment: Please provide more information on what exactly you aleady tried to do, what your goal is, and what your problem is. See also [ask].

Comment: @morxa I don't understand the downvotes, he wants a spark application to be long running and listen to HTTP requests, his problem is the app exits after computation, he tried a simple while loop to keep it alive but is wondering if Spark provides such capabilities out of the box...

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk not sure about that, spark server is long running app on which you can submit spark jobs or fire sql queries.
NiFi is more suitable for such usecases, it supports HTTP endpoints.

Comment: @shekhar you can submit new jobs true but you need to do the computation again and again, with Spark Streaming and SQL you can save the results as an in-memory table and then get them fast in real time. It really depends on your use-case.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk with your comment, the question becomes clear. Without it, I couldn't figure out what exactly the question was. I would still suggest editing the question such that it becomes clearer.

Comment: In other words, I just want to save the middle computerd data so I can update it when new data comes in. I don't want to compute the whole data again. It costs a lot time.

Answer (score 3):

Spark doesn't have such features out of the box. Spark streaming does via [awaitTermination()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html#awaitTermination()) method which you call on the `StreamingContext`. Then you just need to implement a `HTTP` endpoint in your Spark application.

Using Spark Streaming functionality would be the easiest, you can still leave your Spark jobs to use regular RDDs and not DStreams, you can use the StreamingContext just for the `awaitTermination`.

If you don't want to use Spark Streaming you still probably can have a look at how they implement it using locks here [ContextWaiter#waitForStopOrError()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/ContextWaiter.scala#L58)

Comment: I will implement a HTTP endpoint for a try.